# PHP - preg_match - How to match a string upper/lower case with anything before or after it?

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a part of a function that goes like this:

```
if (preg_match("#\bscript\b#",$userInput))
{
    $bannedWord = 'script';
    logHax();
    return TRUE;
}
```

This is causing a problem for what I am trying to accomplish because it will only match the exact word "script" and not variations of it, like "ScriPt" or "`<script>`".

What I would like to have is the examples of the not matched strings along with the original string return true.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://php.net/strip_tags

Comment: @Frits thank you, that does apply. But it will not be entirely suitable in this case.

Comment: You can make it suitable by passing your allowed set of HTML tags like: `strip_tags($untrusted_html, '<p><a><b><u><i>');` this will allow only simple HTML markup tags.

Comment: @Frits The problem with that is that is will not be entirely effective at matching the differnt variations that I am aiming for, e.g. `<script src="bla...`. It is also the case that I am not only trying to match tags, but events too. Please see the post I have chosen below as the correct answer for the most suitable solution in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How's this:

```
if (preg_match("/<script\b[^>]*>/i",$userInput))
{
    $bannedWord = 'script';
    logHax();
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm you are a legend! Could you please explain your use of the two /'s I see they are to hold the string along with a regular expression?

Comment: The /'s in my code are liek the #'s in yours, the are the delimiters(?) of the expression, IE everything inside of them is the expression, the i after the last / says "make this case insensitive", <script\b[^>] is a little more complicated, basically it says "match <script followed by anything but not a >" and then the final > matches the close of the opening tag. phew!

Comment: I highly recommend having a read of this website, as mentioned by another user here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Wow that is alot more complicated, are you some kind of regex god? :)

Comment: While my ego totally appreciates the compliment, I am far from being anything above "getting by" with regular expressions. I do find them fascinating though, this just happens to be similar to something I have done before and could apply here.

Comment: I do find them interesting too, hence the question. I have only really found `html5pattern.com` as anything that has been of use to me though, so the link was a great addition. In anycase thank you for your advice/suggestion, i really appreciate it!

Comment: `#^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$#` my prized email regex as a thanks!

Comment: :D Here's my super short probably crap email validator regex /\w[\.\w]+@\w[\.\w]+/

Comment: @BlackberryFan you regex doesn't seem to validate my email address! myemail+stackoverflow@mydomain.com oh noes! back to the drawing board. There is actually a standards document on the allowed format of an email address, base your regex on that. My check for email is usually something like `$email !== ""` or if I'm feeling up to it `strstr($email, "@")`. Even if the email address _looks_ valid you don't know if it actually receives mail, I find the exercise profoundly useless.

Comment: @Frits I see now that this regex will only work when used in html 5 pattern validation. I have made a big mistake in using the same regex as the backup that is run through the php validation process. So you have proved a valid point. But as far as the regex goes, it seems to work for html5 pattern validation only, and matches things like .co.uk too. I appreciate your input, wise words!

Comment: @Dale thanks i have found the backout to run on the php side! :)

Comment: @Frits What I am basically trying to in that regard, is run the html validation for browsers that support it, but still have a backup for browsers that dont, and that backup should ideally follow along the lines that you speak! - As a side note, I dont think its completely useless, there is always going to be that one guy that does make a mistake, sure he more than likely will not acknowledge your accomplishment, but the lack of those little hiccups give the website a more professional feel in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Case-insensitive matching:

```
preg_match("#\bscript\b#i",$userInput)
```

Note the `i`.  Also note that this ***the first example*** in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
<?php
// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search
if (preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

Cheers

Comment: Alright thanks alot, that helps :) but what about the before and after part?

Comment: Can you please update your original post to ask a single, clear question?  It's not clear to me what you're after.

Comment: Thank you for your input Madbreaks it did solve the first problem but as in the second example, what i was lacking was the regular expression to match any characters before and after the string. like "`<`"string"`>`"

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to match "anything" before or after the string (not just a word), then you do not even need preg_match here, bacuse you could do something like this:

```
$userInputLower = strtolower($userInput);
if (strpos($userInputLower, 'script') !== false)
{
    $bannedWord = 'script';
    logHax();
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: This will match "scripts", etc.

Comment: Thanks, and I've edited the post to make it clearer, and deleted my part of our little "argument".

Comment: Hey and since you edited it, I was able to remove the down-vote.  win/win.  Cheers.