# Preg_match case insensitive

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to make this preg_match case insensitive

```
$mot=/"#".$_POST['nom']."#";
if (preg_match($mot,$line)){ $existe=true;break 1;}
```

I know I have to add /i but it's not working!

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148297/php-preg-match-how-to-match-a-string-upper-lower-case-with-anything-before-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `i` after the search

```
$mot="#".$_POST['nom']."#i";
if (preg_match($mot,$line)){ $existe=true;break 1;}
```

Comment: remove the preceeding / or match it with it as above